# How to animate a point moving from left to middle and from middle to right of the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have 2 `dataframe`s that I want to use for animation:

```
first = dplyr::tibble(name = "first",
                        name_anim = paste0("hi", 1:100),
                        label = "hi",
                        x = seq(0, 0.25, length.out = 100),
                        y = 0.5)

second = dplyr::tibble(name = "second",
                        name_anim = paste0("bye", 1:100),
                        label =  "bye",
                        x = seq(first$x[100], first$x[100] + 0.25, length.out = 100),
                        y = 0.5)
```

I want my animation to show "hi" from left to middle, and from the middle I want the point "hi" to become "bye".

What I have tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

g = ggplot(data = rbind(first, second), aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point(size = 15, alpha = 0.3, aes(col = name)) +
        geom_text(aes(label = label)) +
        guides(color = "none")

g + gganimate::transition_states(name_anim)
```

which gives the following animation:

[image]

There are 2 problems I want to solve:

1. The animation should start from left to middle, and then middle to right. Currently, it starts from middle to right, and then left to middle.
2. The moving point "jumps" back from time to time. (Why?) I want to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the transition states are ordered according to `name_anim`, but these have a lexicographic ordering that doesn't match the row ordering ("bye1" starts before "hi1" because it comes first alphabetically). If you want smooth row-wise transitions, you can use something like `transition_time` after inserting a simple 1:200 sequence column.

```r
ggplot(data = within(rbind(first, second), name_anim <- 1:200), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(size = 15, alpha = 0.3, aes(col = name)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label)) +
  guides(color = "none") + 
  gganimate::transition_time(name_anim/50)
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to wrap that in `gganimate::animate( [code above], nframes = 200)` for smoother animation. The default renders 100 frames, but you have 200 steps to display, leading to a slightly blurred output.